# How can i create dxdiag.txt file automatic ? ( DirectX information text file )

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file, directx

I have a .BAT files i called it : DxDiag.BAT
This is the content :

```
:: 24.07.2013
:: Dxdiag Miner 1.1 by me .
:: Feel free to redistribute and/or modify the file at will, but it'd be nice if you were to give the author credit.

:: Turn off echoing commands to the console, set colour to light green.
@echo off
Color 0A

echo Dxdiag Miner v1.1

:: Check for dxdiag.exe, in case not found go to Dxdiag_Not_Found.
echo Checking for dxdiag.exe...
if not exist %systemroot%\system32\dxdiag.exe GOTO Dxdiag_Not_Found
echo Dxdiag.exe found.

:: Execute dxdiag.exe, pass the path to the file.
echo Creating dxdiag file, please stand by...
%systemroot%\system32\dxdiag.exe /t %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\testing\testing\SF_24-07-13\dxdiag.txt
echo Dxdiag file created under the name of "dxdiag.txt" at %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
:: Open the newly created file.
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\dxdiag.txt

exit


:Dxdiag_Not_Found
echo Dxdiag.exe was not found. Please contact support for further help.
pause
exit
```

The first problem is that i want it to create the text file directly in a specific directory :

```
%systemroot%\system32\dxdiag.exe /t %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\testing\testing\SF_24-07-13\dxdiag.txt
```

The problem is that now the directory in the end is : SF_24-07-13
But sometimes it will be another date for example the directory will be : SF_28-07-13

So how can i change/set it in the BAT file to find each time the correct directory ?

What i wanted to do in c# that every user in windows if its xp vista 7 or 8 will click a button it will run the BAT file and create the dxdiag text file with all the information.

This is what i did now but it's not working :

```
:: 13.08.2011
:: Dxdiag 
:: Feel free to redistribute and/or modify the file at will, but it'd be nice if you were to give the author credit.

:: Turn off echoing commands to the console, set colour to light green.
@echo off
Color 0A

echo Dxdiag Miner v1.1

:: Check for dxdiag.exe, in case not found go to Dxdiag_Not_Found.
echo Checking for dxdiag.exe...
if not exist %systemroot%\system32\dxdiag.exe GOTO Dxdiag_Not_Found
echo Dxdiag.exe found.

:: Execute dxdiag.exe, pass the path to the file.
echo Creating dxdiag file, please stand by...
echo off
set today=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%
echo %today%
%systemroot%\system32\dxdiag.exe /t %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_today\dxdiag.txt
echo Dxdiag file created under the name of "dxdiag.txt" at %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
:: Open the newly created file.
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\dxdiag.txt

exit


:Dxdiag_Not_Found
echo Dxdiag.exe was not found. Please contact support for further help.
pause
exit
```

The part i added is :

```
echo off
set today=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%
echo %today%
%systemroot%\system32\dxdiag.exe /t %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_today\dxdiag.txt
```

I did SF_today also tried before SF_%today%
The reason im adding SF_ before is that the directory is like this :

```
C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_24-07-13
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a Windows batch script question, to get the date, you can use the following command

```
echo %date%
```

This generate the output as **Wed 07/24/2013**, to convert the date to the format you want, you can use

```
%date:~i,n%
```

where i is the start index of the sub string and n is number of characters to get. for example %date:~10,4% will get 2013(4 digits for year)

full code

```
echo off
set today=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%
echo %today%
```

this will get the date string of today, the output is 24-07-2013, you can then insert this string to your script.

Comment: zdd thanks . Please look at my question i have edited it now with what i have tried so far according to your solution but i did something wrong since the file is not created in the directory i wanted .

Comment: I think you should change SF_today to SF_%today%, %today% refer to the value of variable today while today refer to the pure string.